# Can not customize points in rgl plot3D

Tags: r, macos, rgl

I am trying to customize points in my `3D pca` chart, but whatever I do, they just remain as points, and their size can not be changed:

```
with(df_new, plot3d(PC1,PC2,PC3, col = color, type="p", radius = 0.5))
```

> sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: 
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/
vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: 
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/
libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     
datasets  methods   base
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using `radius` to change the size of the points,  but `radius` only applies when you print spheres using `type="s"`. To change the size of the points,  use `size`.

```
with(df_new, plot3d(PC1,PC2,PC3, col = color, type="p", size = 0.5))
```

Although size=0.5 will be very small.